# Adding classes to fields in customized Rails form templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a template to my Rails app forms using this recipe [here](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/02/01/customising-scaffold-views-in-ruby-on-rails/), i.e., customizing the file **lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb**.

All I want is to make all the inputs with type="text" to have the same class="form-control", because I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Now, all these inputs are generated by this line in the template:

```
<%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.column_name %> %>
```

My problems are:

1. I didn't understand completely the syntax of this line, what it is exactly saying, then it is hard to modify it according to my needs; and,
2. I tried to substitute this line for other options, but none worked and I always get runtime errors.

May someone help me with some clue about what to do? Or at least explain me the syntax of the line generating these inputs now, so I can continue myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining what is happening here:

```
<%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.column_name %> %>
```

The first method `field_type` of a generated attribute is basically getting the field type that rails needs to generate for this field. Looking at the [method implementation](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Generators/GeneratedAttribute/field_type) you will find what it does:

```
# File railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb, line 66
  def field_type
    @field_type ||= case type
      when :integer              then :number_field
      when :float, :decimal      then :text_field
      when :time                 then :time_select
      when :datetime, :timestamp then :datetime_select
      when :date                 then :date_select
      when :text                 then :text_area
      when :boolean              then :check_box
      else
        :text_field
    end
  end
```

The same goes for the second method 'column_name', It is quite self explanatory by looking at the [source](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Generators/GeneratedAttribute/column_name):

```
# File railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb, line 116
  def column_name
    @column_name ||= reference? ? "#{name}_id" : name
  end
```

If you wonder what the `<%%` stands for: It is escaping ERB code, so it will result a single `<%` in final generated template.

Now, to achieve what you want, do like this:

```
<%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.column_name %>, class: '<%= attribute.field_type %> form-control' %>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still getting an error in <%= column.field_type %>. It says "Variable or method not found".

Comment: Sorry, my bad. where it is `column.field_type` it should be `attribute.field_type`. I corrected the original answer.

Comment: I should add that the first part of class declaration is optional. It will just add a class named like the type of the attribute, in case you want to add specific css style based on that. but for the sake of simplicity, you can just use this:  
`<%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.column_name %>, class: 'form-control' %>`

Comment: It seems in the next few days I'll be full of questions involving neo4j and Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947181/dont-want-to-display-neo4j-relations-in-a-form